Not able to resolve QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs: 0, but got: 2'
I am getting error:
32 vqc.fit(X_train, X_test)
33 
34 # Evaluate the classifier

15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/neural_networks/neural_network.py in _validate_input(self, input_data)
132 
    133         if shape[-1] != self._num_inputs:
--> 134             raise QiskitMachineLearningError(
    135                 f"Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension "
    136                 f"is not equal to the number of inputs: "

QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs: 0, but got: 2.'

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import VQC
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

# Sample data for demonstration purposes
# Replace this with your actual data
scaled_data = np.random.rand(150, 2)  # Replace with your scaled data
y = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=150)  # Replace with your labels

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_data, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Define the number of qubits based on the feature dimension
num_qubits = X_train.shape[1]

# Define the quantum feature map and ansatz with correct parameters
feature_map = TwoLocal(num_qubits=num_qubits, entanglement='linear') #, rotation_blocks=['ry', 'rz'], entanglement_gate='cz')
ansatz = TwoLocal(num_qubits=num_qubits, entanglement='linear')#, rotation_blocks=['ry', 'rz'], entanglement_gate='cz')

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = COBYLA()

# Initialize the VQC classifier with unique parameter names
vqc = VQC(feature_map=feature_map, ansatz=ansatz, optimizer=optimizer)

# Train the quantum classifier
vqc.fit(X_train, X_test)


Have you tried using ZZFeatureMap? The issue here is how you map your data onto the circuit. You want to map [x1,x2] onto some 1D label, which means that our featuremap should just have two tunable variables, while your feature_map circuit has more than two parameters, thus there is a mismatch between expected data shape and what you are giving it.
To put what I'm saying in code, replace your featuremap to be
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(X_train.shape[1], entanglement='linear')

(I'm avoiding using num_qubits here as its more modelling data points/parameters of gate rotations and not individual qubits).
It should still be possible to use two local as a feature map, but you have to cautious on how you map the data onto the gates such that there exists only two varaibles. Here is an example I modified from the documentation.
entangler_map = [[0, 1], [1,0]] #size should be num of params
feature_map = TwoLocal(2, 'x', 'crx', entangler_map, reps=1)

This featuremap might not be of the best design, but it shouldn't throw an error. You can increase the qubits and try messing around with what they have in the documentation linked above.
